# Rails scope based upon sum of has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Project
  has_many :tasks
  monetize :budget_cents # to create :budget
end

class Task
  belongs_to :project
  monetize :cost_cents # to create :cost
end
```

I want to create a scope for `Project.over_budget` which involves summing the cost of the associated tasks.

In my mind it looks something like this:

`scope :over_budget, ->{ where('budget_cents <= ?', tasks.map(&:cost_cents).sum) }`

Other things I've tried:

`scope :over_budget, -> { joins(:tasks).where('budget <= ?', tasks.map(&:cost).sum) }`

`scope :over_budget, -> { |proj| joins(:tasks).where('budget <= ?', proj.tasks.map(&:cost).sum) }`

`scope :over_budget, -> { |proj| where('budget <= ?', Task.where('project_id=?', proj.id).map(&:cost).sum) }`

`scope :over_budget, -> { |proj| joins(:tasks).where('budget <= ?', Tasks.where('project_id=?', proj.id).map(&:cost).sum) }`

This actually returns without error, but for all Tasks, not the associated:

`scope :over_budget, ->{ where('budget_cents <= ?', Task.map(&:cost_cents).sum) }`

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  scope :over_budget, -> { joins(:tasks).group(:id).having('sum(tasks.cost_cents) > budget_cents') }
end
```

*@chiperific edit:*
The above threw an `ambiguous` error, but it worked when I modified it slightly:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  scope :over_budget, -> { joins(:tasks).group(:id).having('sum(tasks.cost_cents) > projects.budget_cents') }
end
```

### Explanation:

- `Project.joins(:tasks)` will result to something like:

  ```
  | projects.id | projects.budget_cents | tasks.id | tasks.cost_cents |   
  | ----------- | --------------------- | -------- | ---------------- |
  | 1           | 5                     | 1        | 2                |
  | 1           | 5                     | 2        | 3                |
  | 1           | 5                     | 3        | 1                |
  | 2           | 10                    | 4        | 1                |
  ```
- then, appending `.group(:id)` to `Project.joins(:tasks)` above, it results now to something like:

  ```
  | projects.id | projects.budget_cents | tasks.id | tasks.cost_cents |   
  | ----------- | --------------------- | -------- | ---------------- |
  | 1           | 5                     | 1        | 2                |
  | 2           | 10                    | 4        | 1                |
  ```
- then, finally appending `.having('sum(tasks.cost_cents) > budget_cents')` to `Project.joins(:tasks).group(:id)`, it results now to something like:

  ```
  | projects.id | projects.budget_cents | tasks.id | tasks.cost_cents | sum(tasks.costs_cents) |
  | ----------- | --------------------- | -------- | ---------------- | ---------------------- |
  | 1           | 5                     | 1        | 2                | 6
  ```

  - notice that the `projects.id = 2` row no longer exists above, because its `sum(tasks.costs_cents)` only sums to `1`

Comment: This failed: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "budget_cents" is ambiguous`

Comment: But this worked: `scope :over_budget, -> { joins(:tasks).group(:id).having('sum(tasks.cost_cents) > projects.budget_cents') }`

Comment: And +1 for the full explanation!

Comment: @Chiperific ahh true! It worked on mine though :D probably better to use yours just above as well because `projects.budget_cents` is more explicit than mine: `budget_cents` :D No problem! Glad to help!